# HSQLDB not properly recognizing Primary Key from JPA Annotations + Getting Integrity constraint violation

Tags: oracle, java-8, hsqldb, dbunit, hibernate-5.x

We use Oracle for our production Database and HSQLDB for our In-memory Unit Test Database and DBUnit. I am loading some predefined data from dataset file. Both environments use Hibernate(Now I am upgrading to 5.0.3 from 3.5) as the JPA provider. The following code works properly in production, but throws SQL Error: -104, SQLState: 23505 - integrity constraint violation: unique constraint or index violation when run under jUnit. When I am creating a new record, id is populating with 1 instead of max id from dataset file.

Please let me know any help.

Here is the entities, test class and dataset files.

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "RS")
public class Schedule {

  @Id
  @Column(name = ID)
  @SequenceGenerator(name = SEQ_GENERATOR_NAME,
                     sequenceName = SEQ_DB_NAME )
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO,
                  generator =SEQ_GENERATOR_NAME)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = NAME, unique = true)
  @Size(message = "{2010}")
  @NotBlank(message = "{2000}")
  private String name;
```

ResourceTest:

```
public class ResourceTest extends AbstractTestNGJerseyDBUnitTest {
    private static final Long EXISTING_RATE_SCHEDULE_ID        = 6L;
    private static final Long NON_EXISTING_RATE_SCHEDULE_ID    = 999999L;
    private static final Long RATE_SCHEDULE_ID_WITH_2_PRODUCTS = 8L;

    @Override
    public String getDataSetFileName() {
        return "dataset/ResourceTest_DBUnit.xml"; }

    @Override
    protected Class[] resourcesToRegister() {
        return new Class[]{Resource.class};
    }

    @Test
    public void test_endpointName() {
        final String endpointName = Resource.RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER;
        Assert.assertEquals(endpointName, "/schedules");
    }

    @Test
    public void test_create() {
        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        final ObjectNode rootNode = mapper.createObjectNode();
        rootNode.put(NAME, "test_create");
        rootNode.put(DESCRIPTION, "...");
        rootNode.put(CODE, "111");
        rootNode.put(STATUS_ID, Status.ACTIVE.name());

        final Response response =
                target(Resource.RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER).request()
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .build("POST", Entity.json(rootNode))
                        .invoke();

        Assert.assertEquals(Response.Status.fromStatusCode(response.getStatus()), Response.Status.CREATED);
    }
```

DataSet file:

```
<dataset>
    <RS ID="1" NAME="AlreadyTaken" DESCRIPTION="..." CODE="777" STATUS="ACTIVE" CREATED_BY="jpayer" CREATED_DATE="2014-01-01 00:00:00.0" UPDATED_BY="jpayer" UPDATED_DATE="2014-01-01 00:00:00.0"/>
    <RS ID="2" NAME="FOO" DESCRIPTION="desc" CODE="1111" STATUS="ACTIVE" CREATED_BY="jpayer" CREATED_DATE="2014-01-01 00:00:00.0" UPDATED_BY="jpayer" UPDATED_DATE="2014-01-01 00:00:00.0"/>

</dataset>
```